# Flutter ios error : Flutter/Flutter.h not found Xcode 13

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, xcode13, flutter-ios

I try to run flutter project both of Android studio and xcode and get fatal error Flutter/Flutter.h not found. I stucked on this point. Please help me

this is my dependencies:

dependencies:
flutter_localizations:
sdk: flutter
animations: ^2.0.1
#webview_flutter: ^3.0.4
audioplayers: ^0.20.1
buttons_tabbar: ^1.2.0
chewie: ^1.0.0
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.6
cupertino_tabbar: ^2.0.0
dio: ^4.0.0
equatable: null
firebase: ^9.0.2
firebase_core: ^1.10.0
firebase_messaging: ^12.0.1
firebase_auth: any
flutter:
sdk: flutter
flutter_bloc: ^7.3.0
flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.5
flutter_local_notifications: ^9.1.3
flutter_slidable: ^2.0.0
flutter_svg: ^1.1.1+1
flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.8.2
flutter_windowmanager: ^0.2.0
firebase_messaging_platform_interface: ^4.1.0
get_it: ^7.2.0
google_fonts: ^3.0.1
http: ^0.13.3
im_stepper: ^1.0.1+1
image_picker: ^0.8.4
intl: ^0.17.0
introduction_screen: ^3.0.2
pin_code_text_field: ^1.8.0
retrofit: ^3.0.1+1
shared_preferences: ^2.0.7
solid_bottom_sheet: ^0.1.9
url_launcher: ^6.0.13
video_player: ^2.2.7
video_viewer: ^1.2.7
youtube_player_flutter: ^8.0.0
flutter_cache_manager: ^3.3.0
keyboard_actions: ^4.0.1
curved_navigation_bar: any
lottie: any
version_check: ^0.2.1
package_info_plus: ^1.4.2
store_redirect: ^2.0.1
fluttertoast: ^8.0.8

flutter_screenutil: ^5.3.1

Answer (score 0):

1. Backup `ios/Runner` folder.
2. Delete the `ios` folder.
3. Run `flutter create (your project name)`. in the previous folder where you have your project`(cd users/user/"projects_folder")` (this will recreate your `ios` folder).
4. Paste your Runner backup in the `ios` folder (into the project).
5. Open `Runner.xcworkspace` (into `ios` folder) and there, check the Version, the Bundle ID, all the info.
6. (If do you Have Firebase, you have to copy and paste again the Google `Service-Info.Plist` into the `Runner` folder (Always through Xcode) (If do you do this manually, it doesn't work).

Finally, flutter run and should work!

If flutter run fails:

1. `cd ios`
2. `pod install`
3. `cd ..`
4. `flutter run`